# Connect IMSL library to Intel Fortran in Visual Studios

Tags: fortran, visual-studio-setup, imsl

I try to connect the IMSL library (version 6.0) to Intel Fortran (version 11.1) in Visual Studio (version 2008). The IMSL library is added to the path like this:

`$C:\Program Files (x86)\VNI\imsl\fnl600\Intel64\lib`

and the "includes" are there as well

1. `$C:\Program Files (x86)\VNI\imsl\fnl600\Intel64\include\dll`
2. `$C:\Program Files (x86)\VNI\imsl\fnl600\Intel64\include\static`

The program I run to test the installation is:

```
PROGRAM main

USE RNUN_INT
USE RNSET_INT
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: ISEED
REAL :: R(5)

ISEED = 123457
CALL RNSET (ISEED)
CALL RNUN (R)

END PROGRAM main
```

The result I get is `Error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [RNUN_INT]`

What am I missing?

Comment: It's obvious that you are not telling your build system where to look for the `.mod` files for `rnun_int` (nor, probably, for `rnset_int`).

Comment: Yes, I can understand that but what else is missing? I thought it would be enough with just adding the path to the library and to "include".

Comment: Are the `.mod` files in one of those directories ?

Comment: Yes, there are over 2000 .mod files in each directory.

Comment: OK, so my memory of VS is getting a little hazy, but you have to ensure that the compilation phase finds the `.mod` files, i.e. they're needed before linking.  I have a dim recollection of requiring `additional includes` in the compilation settings.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. After reading at Intel's forum I realized that " INCLUDE 'link_fnl_shared.h' " was missing in the beginning of the main-file. Thanks for the support.

Comment: OK, that's good to know.  You should either answer the question -- answering your own questions is perfectly acceptable here (so long as it's a good answer !) -- or delete the question.  Either way, it keeps the site tidy and removes the question from the 'unanswered' lists.